# Extjs: Modify link (<a>) 'on click'

Tags: html, dom, extjs, hyperlink

I have created a *HTML* link (`<a>`) using the *Extjs BoxComponent* and it works just fine. But instead of having a fixed URL associated with the link, I want to be able to update the `href` property when the user clicks the link.

In the code below the `href` is updated when the user cliks the link and I can verify this using FireBug on the HTML element. But the new page opening is missing my addition to the `href`.

**Question**:
Is it too late to modify the `href` on `onClick` or is it because I am modifying the `href` in the wrong way?

**Code**:

```
xtype: 'box',
html: '<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Link to google</a>',        
listeners: {
    render: function (c) {          
        c.getEl().on(
            'click',
            function() {
                this.el.child('a', true).href = 'www.google.com/#q=' + some_dynamic_value;
            },
            c,
            { stopEvent: false }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this can work by using the `mousedown` event, instead of the `click` event.

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/sadkinson/rF5TQ/15/

Comment: That looks good, but I fear that this can be considered as a *hole* in the security (if **BugFinder** is right about the `click` event) and eventually will be closed. But thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that by the time the click has happened changing the URL within it is too late. Is it not possible that whatrever causes your link to need updating can be done when that is changed rather than waiting till the user has clicked the link?

I would imagine a number of browsers would ignore this, simply because it would be an efficient way of being malicious. Putting a link to say "google" and then redirecting you to some virus ridden site etc, as even the most sensible user looking to see where a link would take them would see google until it was too late.

Comment: #1 - yes it is possible, but I am still curious to whether this can be done or not :)
#2 - I can imagine that you might be right on this one :S

Comment: If you're standing up, could you change the shoe of the foot while you're standing on it? It would seem odd not to be able to override it as most things can be, but, Im thinking to prevent malicious behavior this would be also a sensible thing not to do.. As a side thought, You may also need to return false for that section.. otherwise it may change it, but because it didnt get false go on and do the original behavior